# Are children of apostate parents considered Muslim?

Tags: fiqh, apostasy

Consider the following situation.

There are parents, who leave the Islam and they will be atheists, or non-Muslims. Which is a serious crime, but it is possible.

They have children, and these children are grown up in other religion (or to be an atheist), and they never hear from the Islam.

Will these children be considered Muslims (because their parents were once Muslims), or they will have non-Muslim status?

P.s. It is a *hypothetical* question, actually I never heard any similar case. I am just curious, what happens in such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A child has no identity in that.  Being raised by Muslim or non-Muslim parents doesn't necessarily mean the children are upon that religion.  Islam is a choice and cannot be compelled upon the children by their parents.  Once the child has reached the capacity of sound judgment, they are to follow what they conclude to be the correct and reasonable path.  That's why a child who was raised by Muslim parents, and when reached adulthood, decides not to be Muslim; isn't considered an apostate.

So technically there's no difference between a 'Muslim child' from a 'Non-Muslim child.'  They both have the same identity.

Answer (score 2):

`Will be these children considered muslims (because their parents were once muslims), or they will have non-muslim status?`

They will not. Children are considered Muslims and if they die before puberty will enter heaven in Islam.

Also this is not a hypothetical situation, I know many Muslims who reverted and their kids are on what they reverted to.

Comment: Children aren't automatically considered Muslim.  Where in the Quran did you derive that from?

Comment: It is not from the Quran, but rather a Hadith that all children are born in `Fitrah` mode.

Comment: Fitrah doesn't mean Muslim, it literally means nothing i.e.no belief or no concept...These are two different Arabic words with separate meanings.  We shouldn't say what's not been said.

Comment: @Sayyid Fitrah has two meaning by scholars, one being originality the other Muslim. Majority of the Salaf, including Ibn Abd Albir and Alqortabi from Abi Hirira, Ibn Shihab and others go for the lateral: `التمهيد (18/72) & (18/76)` and `والجامع لأحكام القرآن (14/25).`